# Xamarin.Forms / KeyPressEventArgs

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was wondering if anything is close to KeyPressEventArgs in Xamarin Forms, since I need to validate some fields. here is an example with windows forms.

```
    public static bool ValideringTlf(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        return (e.Handled = char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == 127 ? false : true);
    }
    public static bool ValideringNavn(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        return (e.Handled = char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == 32 || e.KeyChar == 127 ? false : true);
    }
    public static bool ValideringVejnr(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        return (e.Handled = char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == 127 ? false : true);
    }
    public static bool ValideringPostnr(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        return (e.Handled = char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == 127 ? false : true);
    }
```

Btw these numbers are from Ascii Tabel.

Answer (score 0):

The [TextChanged](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=E%3AXamarin.Forms.Entry.TextChanged) event on Entry has a TextChangedEventArgs with NewTextValue and OldTextValue properties.  This should allow you to create an event handler to validate an entry.